# Why freeze application when use Coroutine in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

In my application I want call API every **60 sec** and for this I want use `Coroutines`.
I write below codes, but after some time my application has freeze and user can not use this application!

**My codes :**

```
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

...

private fun callLoopApi(): Job {
    return coroutineScope.launch {
        while (isActive) {
            delay(10000)
            presenter.callApi(5)
            Log.e("CoroutineLog", "CallApi")
        }
    }
}
```

**ApiCall codes:**

```
override fun callApi(id: Int) {
        if (view.checkNetworkConnection()) {
            view.showLoader()
            disposable = ApiClientLive.getInstance().apisUseCase()
                .getTeamInfo(id)
                .applyIoScheduler()
                .subscribe({ response ->
                    view.hideLoader()
                    when (response.code()) {
                        in 200..202 -> {
                            response.body()?.let { itBody ->
                                itBody.data.let { itData ->
                                    itData?.results?.let { itResult ->
                                        view.loadTeamInfo(itResult)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

I want call API every 60 sec and update my UI.
How can I fix this problem?!

Comment: What does `callApi()` look like? Is it a blocking function?

Comment: @Tenfour04 , No just method for show items. I used MVP

Comment: We can’t tell you what’s wrong if you don’t share it…

Comment: What is this `isRunLoopedApi` boolean? Note that if it switches to false, this code will start a busy loop, blocking the main thread entirely and freezing the application. Didn't you mean to place `delay()` outside of `if`?

Comment: @brootCan you help me my friend? I want just callApi every 60sex and then update UI. please

Comment: @broot I updated my codes. please see that

Comment: As others said, you need to share `callApi()` contents. Most probably it performs a blocking operation.

Comment: @broot please see my above post. I updated it

Answer (score 0):

You launch it in the main tread
[sample](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv)
Change it

```
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
private fun callLoopApi(): Job {
    return coroutineScope.launch {
        while (isActive) {
            if (isRunLoopedApi) {
                presenter.callApi(5)
                delay(60000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    private fun callLoopApi(): Job {
    return coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default + "BackgroundCoroutine") {
        while (isActive) {
            if (isRunLoopedApi) {
                presenter.callApi(5)
                delay(60000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not necessarily wrong to launch a long-running coroutine on the main thread. If its purpose is to update UI from time to time then it doesn't make sense to execute it in the background thread only to immediately switch to main.

Comment: Thanks my friend. but when use `Dispatchers.IO` show me thread error for update UI

Comment: It is the right behavior. Look like you are a beginner. Check the https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

To do work NOT on main thread and to avoid UI freezes, use Dispatchers.IO and for UI, use Dispatchers.Main.
For example, you can do it next way:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    //some work
    //work is finished
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        //do smth with result on UI, for example show result on UI
    }
}
```

also if `delay(10000)` is called on UI thread, it freezes everything on your UI